# How can I verify a mocked object is removed from a mocked list?

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to write a unit test for this method:

```
public void AddItem( Cart cart, Item item )
{
    var duplicates = cart.Items.OfType<Item>()
                         .Where( i => i.Key == item.Key )
                         .ToList();

    foreach ( var duplicate in duplicates )
    {
        cart.Items.Remove( duplicate );
    }

    cart.Items.Add( item );
}
```

I want to verify that duplicate items (items with the same key) are removed from the list before the new one is added. This test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddItemRemovesDuplicateItemsFirst()
{
    const int itemKey = 123;

    var cart = new Mock<Cart>();

    var duplicate = new Mock<Item>();
    duplicate.SetupGet( m => m.Key ).Returns( itemKey );

    cart.SetupGet( m => m.Items ).Returns( new List<Item>
        {
            duplicate.Object
        } );

    var addItem = new Mock<Item>();
    addItem.SetupGet( m => m.Key ).Returns( itemKey );

    var task = GetTask();
    task.AddItem( cart.Object, addItem.Object );

    Assert.AreEqual( 1, cart.Object.Items.Count );
}
```

It fails because `Count` is 2. On the other hand, this test passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddItemRemovesDuplicateItemsFirst()
{
    const int itemKey = 123;

    var cart = new Mock<Cart>();

    cart.SetupGet( m => m.Items ).Returns( new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
                {
                    Key = itemKey
                }
        } );

    var addItem = new Mock<Item>();
    addItem.SetupGet( m => m.Key ).Returns( itemKey );

    var task = GetTask();
    task.AddItem( cart.Object, addItem.Object );

    Assert.AreEqual( 1, cart.Object.Items.Count );
}
```

The only difference is the second one doesn't use a `Mock` object for the list item.

I'm trying to avoid actually creating the objects as in the second approach. How can I get the first to pass?

Comment: Why is it that you want to mock the items? I don't see that you are isolating any behavior, just the value of an int, which you can do on the instantiated object.

Also, there is probably something I don't understand, but could you simply not add the duplicate item to the list instead of removing and readding? It would make the code in your method under test simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the interaction with `Items` that you are testing, you are going to need an object to test, whether it is a concrete instance (as in your second approach), or a mock.

If you use a mock, you'll need to set it up to return the existing items when `OfType` is called. Then you can explicitly verify that the call to `Remove` was made, rather than checking `Count`, something like this (not tested):

```
Items.Verify(
    x => x.Remove(
        It.Is<Item>(
            item => item.Key == itemKey)));
```

Having said that, I can't help thinking that this functionality should be encapsulated in `Cart`, without exposing the `Item` list to be manipulated outside that class. That would make writing the test easier too.

Answer (score 1):

When testing with mocks (e.g. `Mock<Cart>`), you're testing how your code under test *interacts* with the mocks. When testing with real objects (e.g. `Cart`), you're testing the *end result*.

So with the failing test, because you're using mocks, you'll want to test how the mock in being interacted with. Therefore, you want to test that your code is calling the `Remove` method correctly:

```
    cart.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<Item>()));
```

This isn't as good as it can be as you'll want to replace the `It.IsAny<Item>()` with the actually expected item. It just means that you'll have setup a mock for items list too:

```
    var itemsListMock = new Mock<List<Item>>();
    cart.SetupGet( m => m.Items ).Returns(itemsListMock.Object);
    //TODO setup getting 'duplicates' from Where clause
```

Hopefully that's kind of clear and makes sense.